# Nested for loop exercise

Tags: php, for-loop

How can I solve this using php?

Write nested for loops to produce the following output:

Enter a number:5

```
----1
---22
--333
-4444
55555
```

Comment: Nobody here wants to do your homework for you. You'll have to demonstrate at least a little effort. Try something and if you get stuck, show us the code and tell us what went wrong (errors, unexpected output, etc.) and then maybe we can help you.

Comment: I really don't have a solution. Echo depends on the number that client enters. If it's 3, for example, echo must be --1,-22, 333....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 1; $i++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j <= 1; $j++) {
        echo 'Enter a number:5 ----1 ---22 --333 -4444 55555';
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Here is the real answer:

```
$number = 5;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $number; $i++) {
    for ($j = $number; $j >= 1; $j--) {
        if ($i < $j) {
            echo '-';
        } else {
            echo $i;
        }
    }

    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

This code uses two `for` loops. The outer loop creates the rows (iterates from `1` to `$number`), the inner loop creates the characters (iterates from `$number` to `1`). There is a comparison inside the inner loop. If `$i` is less than `$j`, then it prints `-`, otherwise it prints `$i`.

Comment: +0 but made me laugh.

Comment: Classic! Good heckle!

Comment: i prefer the `$i >= 1` version :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought that it's essential that program produces different echo if client enters other than 5. If it's 6, -----1 ----22 ---333 --4444 -55555 666666'

Comment: @Nemchus It was just a joke. Added the real answer now.

Comment: Cpt. Newbie here, no time for jokes :D

Comment: @Nemchus I made the joke because your question didn't show any effort in trying to solve this problem. Next time try to write some code first and add it to your question (even if it doesn't work). See this meta post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: New here, copy that.